# Numerical integration of a function with Dirac delta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, evaluation, special-functions, numerical-value

I have a little question about the numerical integration of a function that includes a Dirac delta.
I have the following function:

```
f[x_,y_,z_]=Cot[x + z] Cot[x - y z] (-Cot[x - y z] Csc[x + z]^2 + y Cot[x + z] Csc[x - y z]^2)
```

Then I have to compute the following integral:

```
NIntegrate[DiracDelta[y - 1] f[x, y, z], {x, 0.1, 0.2}, {y, -Infinity,Infinity},{z, 0, x + y},AccuracyGoal->5]
```

The idea is: evaluate the symbolic integral in the variable 'z', then evaluate the resulting function of 'x' and 'y' for 'y=1' (this is perfermed by the integration of the Dirac delta), then compute the integral on the variable 'x'.

With numerical integration I obtaine the result of '0.',but it is not correct.
I have tried with non-numerical integral:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - 1] f[x, y, z], {x, 0.1, 0.2}, {y, -Infinity,Infinity},{z, 0, x + y}]
```

and I obaine the result of '-142.527'.

I need this numeric integral because, the function f[x,y,z], might not admit a primitive closed function.

Thanks for any tips and helps!

Comment: Since `z` goes past `x` it looks like it diverges?

Comment: I don't think it diverges, infact the analitic integral converges at '-142.527'. I think the problem is in the integration of the Dirac delta function...

Comment: I can use a simplier function like 'f[x_,y_,z_]=x y z', the analitic integral gives the correct result, the nuemrical integral gives me '0'

Comment: @Lorenzo Your `Integrate` expression returns the input with an error: "Integral of Cos[2 x] Csc[x-z]^2 Csc[x+z]^2 DiracDelta[-1+y] Sin[2 z] does not converge on {0, x+y}." on MMA 12.0 (Win10-64). How did you get that -142 numerical value?

Comment: I am sorry, you all are right; I wrote the wrong function. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: The integral `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - 1] f[x, y, z], {x, 0.1, 0.2}, {y, -Infinity,Infinity},{z, 0, x + y}]` makes no sense in math.

Comment: Even `f[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Cot[x + z] Cot[
   x - y* z] (-Cot[x - y z] Csc[x + z]^2 + 
    y Cot[x + z] Csc[x - y* z]^2); NIntegrate[
 1/(1 + (y - 1)^2) /Pi*f[x, y, z], {x, 0.1, 0.2}, {y, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {z, 0, x + y}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]` produces `-5.06639*10^23` and the warnings "Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small." and

Comment: "NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 27 recursive bisections in z near {x,y,z} = {0.422062,0.495129,0.124984}. NIntegrate obtained -5.06639*10^23 and 8.928129785206717`*^23 for the integral and error estimates.".

Comment: @user64494 `NIntegrate`  does not work properly with `DiracDelta` function. An example:`{NIntegrate[DiracDelta[y - 1]*(y + 1), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}], 
  With[{e = 10^-3}, 
   NIntegrate[(e/(\[Pi] (e^2 + (-1 + y)^2)))*(y + 1), {y, -Infinity, 
     Infinity}]], 
  Integrate[
   DiracDelta[y - 1]*(y + 1), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]} // Quiet` you may change to:`e = 10^-4`  .

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Did you pay your attention to `1/(1 + (y - 1)^2) /Pi` instead of `DiracDelta[y-1]` in the integrand?

Comment: @user64494. In my example dosen't work: `NIntegrate[(1/(1 + (y - 1)^2)/Pi)*(y + 1), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]` gives: `7498.53` ,but should be `2`.

Comment: @MariuszIwanyuk: Sorry, your comment is aside of the question under consideration.  Did you pay your attention to `1/(1 + (y - 1)^2) /Pi` instead of `DiracDelta[y-1]` in the integrand?

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica **Can** compute this integral **symbolically**:

```
$Version
(* "13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"*)

f[x_, y_, z_] = Cot[x + z] Cot[
x - y z] (-Cot[x - y z] Csc[x + z]^2 + y Cot[x + z] Csc[x - y z]^2);

Z = Integrate[f[x, y, z], {z, 0, x + y}, Assumptions -> {x > 0, y \[Element] Reals}]

(*Long time computation about few minutes*)

 (*1/2 (-Cos[2 x] Csc[x]^4 + 
 Cos[3 x + y - y (x + y)] Cos[x + y + y (x + y)] Csc[2 x + y]^2 Csc[
 x - y (x + y)]^2)*)

Y = Integrate[DiracDelta[y - 1] Z[[1]], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
(*-(1/2) Cos[2 x] (Csc[x]^4 - Cos[2 + 2 x] Csc[1]^2 Csc[1 + 2 x]^2)*)

X = Integrate[Y, {x, 1/10, 2/10}]
(*-(1/6) (1 + 3 Cos[1/5] + 3 Cos[2/5]) Csc[1/5]^3 + 
1/40 Csc[1]^2 (-2 + 5 Cos[2] (Cot[6/5] - Cot[7/5]) + 
Csc[1] (-5 Csc[6/5] Sin[1/5] + 5 Csc[7/5] Sin[2/5]))*)

X//N
(*-142.527*)
```

Comment: The integral `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - 1] Z[[1]], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x > 0]` makes no sense in math. That was discussed here many times. Both [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) and W. Rudi, Functional analysis say nothing about the definite integrals of distributions.

Comment: @user64494 ,The integral makes sense in math. That was discussed here many times.

Comment: Can you give a serious math reference instead of  your ungrounded claim? TIA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there can be cases of functions f[x,y,z] that can not be integrated symbolically, and I can't use your prescription... For example if the function is 'f[x_,y_,z_]=Exp[-z^2 Exp[-z^2]]' , the symbolic integrate doesen't work...

Comment: @LorenzoBagnasacco. My answer concerned a specific function f[x,z,y] in your question ,not for general.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk. Infact in my question I ask for a generic function 'f[x,y,z]', that can not admit a close primitve function. If you have an aswer about this problem, I'll listen to you. Thanks again!

Comment: @LorenzoBagnasacco You can `NIntegrate` the final integral instead of `Integrate` in @MariuszIwaniuk answer and get the same numerical value.  I believe that is what you wanted.  It will pretty much always fail to do any numerical analysis on a dirac delta, because its zero width requires an infinitely small step size to catch it.  The dirac delta part of the integration needs to be taken care of before the numerical integration.

Comment: And @user64494, the integral makes perfect sense.  It is an example of  the first integral presented in the https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Delta-function paper you referenced me that verified one of my previous answers.